# Why should I use sprites on my mobile site?

Tags: css, sprite, tritium

Why should I use sprites in building the CSS on my mobile site? And how do I implement them while in Tritium?

Answer (score 6):

#### The Why

Put simply: to save on network requests. One request for a sprite at 10kB is much faster over a network than ten requests for ten 1kB images.

Additionally, that one compressed image sprite is going to yield huge savings over the network. For example, take 13 images, each around 4kB. That's 52kB over 13 network requests. With spriting, it can be brought down to 1 image at 12kB over 1 network request. Huge savings!

You don't have to make your own sprites - Moovweb can automatically generate them for you.

#### Implementation

Create a folder with the name **sprites** in the **images** directory - place all your images in here. (You can have multiple folders within the **sprites** folder.) Moovweb automatically generates the sprite and creates a stylesheet in the **stylesheets/globals** directory called `_sprites.scss`. Don't forget to import this stylesheet in `main.scss`.

For example, to create a sprite with all the kitten pictures from a site, place all the kitten images in a folder called **sprites** in the **images** folder. Moovweb creates a larger sprite image in the **images** folder. It also creates a stylesheet, `_sprites.scss`, in the **stylesheets/globals** folder.

In the stylesheet, Moovweb defines a set of classes, mixins and variables for each image. Their name format is `sprites-filename`. For example, in our sprite folder example above, the `cat.png` icon inside the sprites folder would have the class `.sprites-cat`.

You can use the image in one of three ways:

1. Use `@extend` or `@include` under another class/id in your stylesheet to apply the same styles from the image
2. Insert a new element using Tritium with the class of the image: `insert("div", class:"sprites-filename")`
3. Add a class onto an existing element with Tritium: `add_class("sprites-filename")`